# Delete apk in alpha testing to upload a different one with same version code

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

As the title suggest I uploaded an apk earlier in alpha testing mode and published it then needed to change some code. Now I want to upload the apk again but it gives me error that the version is already uploaded. Is there any way to delete the previous apk so that I can upload the new one with the same version code?

Comment: **"Is there any way to delete the previous apk so that I can upload the new one with the same version code?"** - No, you'll have to increase the version number.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change (increase) the version number everytime you upload a new apk version. Mind that this is not the same as the version name which you can change any time in any way you like.

Comment: well, I wonder why Google won't allow us to replace APK with exact same version, even when still in DRAFT mode :(

Comment: @akhyar If they do so the new app with old version code were never updated to users. I suppose their updating system uses version code to detect "new app" and then to send it to users as an update.

Comment: Since Google forces you to supply a ton of other details, like countries/ratings etc.. I don't have to do Create App again do I? How do I navigate to bump release and swap out apk while leaving rest same as first release? And can I take down an alpha release?